# How do you activate the OpenBLAS library with NumPy on Python (linux)?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, multiprocessing, openblas

I'm trying to accelerate matrix multiplication on my own, on python.
I've looked for several ways and one of them was parallel computing on CPU with BLAS on top of numpy.
I've read on documentation that numpy.dot (for matrix multiplication) uses BLAS.
[Link to numpy.dot library.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

> It uses an optimized BLAS library when possible (see numpy.linalg).

However, when I download the OpenBLAS library and try to make it work with my code, it doesn't work at all, the speed is the same as before. The command `htop` in the terminal shows that only one of my 8 cores in my processor is used.

My work environment is one of the latest version of Mint.

To download OpenBLAS I followed one instruction on another stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration), however it doesn't go further than the installation. I first try with shell command:
`sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev`

First I uninstalled numpy with pip:
`pip uninstall numpy`
And installed it after first installing libopenblas.

I didn't cloned the OpenBLAS as mentioned in the URL because I tried to keep it simple.

Then, I tried the following code in my python script:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import os


#Environment for multi-threading
nb_processeurs = str(mp.cpu_count())
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = nb_processeurs
os.environ["BLAS"] = "openblas64_"

print(np.__config__.show())

#Variables
n = 5000
p = 300

# Generate a matrix of 0 and 1 with 30% of 1 and 70% of 0
A = (np.random.rand(n,p)> 0.7).astype(int)
A_t = A.T


#Numpy dot product
start_time = time.time()
C1 = np.dot(A,A_t)
end_time = time.time()
print("NumPy dot product took {} seconds".format(round(end_time - start_time,2)))
```

With `multiprocessing` library I check how many core I have on my CPU then give it to the `os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"]` environment variable.

I wrote `os.environ["BLAS"] = "openblas64_"` because the function `np.__config__.show()` displayed in the terminal that the openblas version I have is `openblas64_`:

```
openblas64__info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas64__lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
None
```

So, by setting the 'os.environ' variable as above, I expected the code to run in parallel, to no avail.

Is it a problem with the installation or with how I wrote the script ?
I'm kind of new to linux ways of installing libraries/packages and make it work so it may come from that. I didn't tried to clone the git for OpenBLAS for this reason.

If any of you have and idea of solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: make sure you set environment variables before importing numpy or it won't take effect

Answer (score 0):

use `conda`.

(why ? Because it handles binaries dependencies better and allows you to install everywhere, not only as part of the system)

- See [The Numpy Installation Guide](https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries).
- See also [This answer how to avoid OpenBlas issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516740/conda-forcing-numpy-and-scipy-to-downgrade-from-openblas-to-non-working-mkl-vers)

Comment: Thank you, i'll give a try and come back to tell you.

Comment: some conda versions of numpy are built with intel MKL instead of openBLAS, but neither is a dependency at install time. They are only required at compile time, so pre-built binaries (like you'd get from pip or conda) side-step needing to install either blas or mkl.